# Pyspark - No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I installed anaconda.
I have this error when working with pyspark.
No such file or directory. What file or directory ?
I see that also i have an ERROR TaskSetManager.

[image]

> ```
> 22/07/03 13:26:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/anaconda3/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or directory
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>   at `enter code here`org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
>   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>   ... 31 more
> 22/07/03 13:26:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (mypc executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run
> ```
>
> program "/home/anaconda3/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or
> directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
> ... 31 more
>
> ```
> 22/07/03 13:26:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
> [Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> /tmp/ipykernel_5618/3726558592.py in <module>
> ----> 1 df.show()
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
>     482         """
>     483         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
> --> 484             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
>     485         else:
>     486             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
>    1307 
>    1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
> -> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
>    1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>    1311 
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>     109     def deco(*a, **kw):
>     110         try:
> --> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
>     112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>     113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>     324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
>     325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> --> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>     327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>     328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.showString.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost
> ```
>
> task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (mypc executor driver):
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/anaconda3/bin/python3":
> error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
> ... 31 more
>
> ```
> Driver stacktrace:
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:472)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:425)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2722)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2722)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2929)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:338)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>   at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>   at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/anaconda3/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or directory
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:209)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
>   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ... 1 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
>   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
>   at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>   ... 31 more
> ```

Comment: We cannot scroll through an image. Pls add the full text (as text)

Comment: Is the classpath properly added or the user(in Jupyter notebook) has appropriate permissions in the path?Pls paste the error trace

Comment: I modified and add the error message completely.